# Jellybean ratingBarStyleSmall is broken

Tags: android, android-view

It seems that the RatingBar widget with `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`  and
 `?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator` is not working on JellyBean 4.1. It shows up on the Eclipse-ADT UI editor but not on the actual device. Is there a fix for this without having to resort to a custom view? Thanks

Note: 
It was working fine on previous platforms. Only on Jellybean it does not appear.

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should provide the layout file and/or code.

Comment: @AndiDog Just a basic layout with the RatingBar widget added.